# Adding a (?i) in the regex causes an error in javascript "invalid regex group"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex

```
/^(?!.*qwerty)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/
```

but every time I add a (?i) in front of the querty it causes an error in javascript "invalid regex group"

Can someone pls tell me why?

Comment: because JS do not supports inline modifiers

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with adding `i` on the place which built for only modifiers. JS won't allow modifiers to be placed inside a regex.

```
/^(?!.*qwerty)[0-9A-Z]*$/i
```

Comment: Thank you for answering . I'm trying to implement this regex in an external grails config when I add the "i" at the last, compilation fails because it is considered as an invalid token. Do you know how to escape this?

Comment: you may also use `RegExp` constructor like, `RegExp("^(?!.*qwerty)[0-9A-Z]*$", "i")`

Answer (score 1):

See the [*Regex Modifiers—Turning them On* at rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#i):

> **Inline Modifier `(?i)`**
>   In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl, Python, Java and Ruby (**but *not* JavaScript**), you can use the inline modifier `(?i)`, for instance in `(?i)cat`.

You might use character classes matching both upper- and lowercase variants:

```
^(?!.*[Qq][Ww][Ee][Rr][Tt][Yy])[0-9a-zA-Z]*$
```

If you can afford a 3rd party [`XRegExp` library](http://xregexp.com/syntax/), you can use the *inline modifiers*:

> A mode modifier uses the syntax `(?imnsuxA)`, where `imnsuxA` is any combination of `XRegExp` flags except `g` or `y`. Mode modifiers provide an alternate way to enable the specified flags.

Here is a demo:

```js
var regex = XRegExp('(?i)^(?!.*qwerty)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$');
document.body.innerHTML = regex.test("Text QwErty");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```